# How to pass generic Object as a Generic parameter on other method in java?

Tags: java, generics

I meet a trouble in using generic method

Compiled class:

```
public class Something<T> {
   public static Something newInstance(Class<T> type){};
   public <T> void doSomething(T input){};
}
```

and my method is:

```
public <S> void doOtherThing(S input){
      Something smt = Something.newInstance(input.getClass());
      smt.doSomething(input); // Error here
}
```

It got error at Compile time:

> no suitable method found for doSomething(T) T cannot be converted to
>   capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object
>   ...

I think there might be a trick to avoid this, please help

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. First there are two separate `T`s. `doSomething`'s `T` is not the same as the class `Something`'s `T`, because `doSomething` is a generic method that declares its own `T`. You should name the two variables differently, because they are unrelated to each other. Then the fact that `doSomething` only uses `T` once as a parameter type, and `T` is unbounded, means that it takes anything, so it is equivalent to `public void doSomething(Object input){}`; the `T` is useless. Same thing with `doOtherThing` -- it is equivalent to `public void doOtherThing(Object input)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `input.getClass()` need be cast to `Class<T>`

```
public <S> void doOtherThing(S input){
      Something smt = Something.newInstance((Class<T>)input.getClass());
      smt.doSomething(input);
}
```

Comment: This is unsafe because of raw type and unchecked casting.

Answer (score 8):

Pass the S class as an argument.

```
public class Something<T>
{
    public static <T> Something<T> newInstance(Class<T> type)
    {
        return new Something<T>();
    }

    public void doSomething(T input){;}

    public <S> void doOtherThing(Class<S> clazz, S input)
    {
        Something<S> smt = Something.newInstance(clazz);
        smt.doSomething(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: But really doOtherThing is rather useless if not static. Basically it's just creating a Something instance and applying doSomething, with generic type S instead of T.

Comment: 2 argument from same class S to use generic, it's slight redundant

Comment: Only way to avoid an unchecked cast warning.

Comment: Actually, for this example, `Class<T> type` is unused, so you don't even need that.

Comment: Interesting. Does the `T` in the `Something<T>` return type reference the argument-inferred generic, or the generic of the lexical class?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk, I have some trouble understanding your question. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Anything like this? (generic type declaration thingy on our newInstance method)

```
public class Something<T> {
   public static <T> Something<T> newInstance(Class<T> type){ return null; }
   public <T> void doSomething(T input){};
}
```

Comment: Nope, It work fine with non-generic variable  (like String)